# difficulty formatting with multirow and multicolumn

Tags: multirow, multicolumn, makecell

I've created a table that (I think) needs `\makecell{}`, `\multirow{}`, and `multicolumn{}` to be displayed properly. The issue is that the spatial arrangement of my elements is not so great.

- The lower and upper subheadings (columns 5 & 6) are not aligned properly.
- Columns 1-4 are not placed sensibly (centered or bottom aligned would work).
- I have to use a hack (`\B`) to space my `\hline` so that it does not overlap text of columns 3 & 4.

Any advice On what I might be doing wrong or a better approach (apologies for the single use nature of the question)?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow, ctable}

\newcommand\B{\rule[-2.5ex]{0pt}{0pt}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption{title}
\small
\begin{tabular}{cccccc}

\specialrule{.2em}{.1em}{.1em} 
\multirow{2}{*}{Condition} & \multirow{2}{*}{\textit{N}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\makecell{Mean Proportion \\ Taxonomic  \\ Responses}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\makecell{Taxonomic \\ Responding Exact \\ Binomial Test \textit{p}}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\makecell{95\% Binomial \\ Confidence Intervals}} \\
\cline{5-6}
& & & & Lower & Upper \B \\ 
\hline
Alien & \textit{n} = 65 & .74 & \\ 
Alike & \textit{n} = 63 & .68 & \\
Similar & \textit{n} = 50 & .68 & \\
No Reminder & \textit{n} = 59 & .40 & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\label{table:e1rt}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some improvements with `booktabs` and code simplification with `\multirowcell` command, since you load `makecell`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow, booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \caption{title}
    \footnotesize\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
    \begin{tabular}{c>{$}c<{$}cccc}
        \toprule
        \multirowcell{3}[-1pt]{Condition} & \multirowcell{3}[-1pt]{$N$} & \multirowcell{3}[-1pt]{Mean Proportion \\ Taxonomic \\ Responses}& \multirowcell{3}[-1pt]{Taxonomic \\\strut Responding Exact \\ Binomial Test $p$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\makecell{95\% Binomial \\ Confidence Intervals}} \\
        \cmidrule(lr){5-6}
        & & & & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Lower} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Upper} \\
        \midrule
        Alien & n = 65 & .74 & \\
        Alike & n = 63 & .68 & \\
        Similar & n = 50 & .68 & \\
        No Reminder & n = 59 & .40 & \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \label{table:e1rt}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think your solution needs `\usepackage{siunitx}`

Comment: @ghonke: With the data you posted, it isn't useful: all numbers in the third column have the same number of digits, so the alignment will be automatic.

Comment: I only mention it because the document fails to compile without it, maybe the error was something else but it seems like I isolated it to presence/absence of that package call, it throws an error here without it: `\begin{tabular}{c>{$}c<{$}cccc}`

Comment: The error happens with the very code in my answer?

Comment: Sorry, no, mistake on my end. thanks for the response it looks much better.

Answer (score 2):

I think you could improve it using `booktabs`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow, booktabs}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \caption{title}
    \footnotesize
    \begin{tabular}{c>{$}c<{$}S[table-format=.2,add-integer-zero=false]ccc}
        \toprule
        \multirow{2}{*}{Condition} & \multirow{2}{*}{$N$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{\makecell{Mean Proportion \\ Taxonomic  \\ Responses}}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\makecell{Taxonomic \\ Responding Exact \\ Binomial Test $p$}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\makecell{95\% Binomial \\ Confidence Intervals}} \\
        \cmidrule{5-6}
        & & & & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Lower} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Upper} \\ 
        \midrule
        Alien & n = 65 & .74 & \\ 
        Alike & n = 63 & .68 & \\
        Similar & n = 50 & .68 & \\
        No Reminder & n = 59 & .40 & \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \label{table:e1rt}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]